# Продакшн версия проекта AngularJS с использованием generator-gulp-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, framework, gulp, build

Возникает проблема при создании продакшн версии проекта. Когда загружаю проект на этапе сборки с использованием команды gulp serve - он работает корректно, но когда собираю продакшн версию в папку dist с использованием команды gulp build - при его дальнейшем открытии запускается только первая страница index.html (роутинг в целом не работает).

Вот ссылка  к репозиторию моего проекта на github:
https://github.com/reflection937/my_lab

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в названии модуля для templateCache в my_lab/gulp/build.js:23
Ваш глобальный модуль называется **MyLabApp**, такой же должен быть там указан.

```
module: 'MyLabApp',
```

Консоль в браузере так и говорит, что не может найти модуль myLab.

Надеюсь помог. Удачи!

P.S. Команда `gulp build` осуществляет лишь сборку билда в папку. Чтобы поднять сервер и посмотреть результат продакшн билда нужна команда `gulp serve:dist`,

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Именно в этом и оказалась ошибка.